# Bootstrap collapsed navbar - I want menu to be aligned to left but it is aligned to right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar, hamburger-menu

I made simple bootstrap navbar which collapses when display window is small. I also added image in that navabar.

Now when I make browser window smaller and hamburger menu appears, I have collapsible menu not aligned to the very left of the webpage, please see the enclosed image below.

I would like to have that collapsible menu aligned to the left, what should I do?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-left logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" height="40px">
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="index.html">title</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="index.html">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Freebies</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

[Screenshot of my collapsed navabar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIHcX.png)

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: As @vanburen said, we won't be able to help without any material to work with.

Comment: Have you tried `float:left`?

Comment: @Tinsten I updated my post with code also I tried float:left to #menu but it gives me nothing

Comment: Do you have any css, excluding the bootstrap css?

Comment: Are you applying any other CSS to your nav because the sample you posted doesn't produce the same results as the image. Also, `narbar-left should be places on your UL, not the collapse div.

Comment: Only that in CSS:
`.nav {
  margin-left:212px;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a media query with your CSS so it doesn't change the mobile view.

**Working Example:**

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    margin-left: 212px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a href="#" class="navbar-left logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f00/fff" height="50px">
      </a>

      <a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="#">title</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Freebies</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No problem and glad it help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes
1)move button tag after image of a
2)Add style attribute like following in img and button tag

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
   
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-left logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" height="40px" style="float:left;">
      </a>
         <button type="button" style="float:left;" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="index.html">title</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="index.html">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Freebies</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```